Unable to wrap a table in "solution" environment
Here are two "sol" environments:
1.
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{sol}[1][\color{EgyptianBlue}\bf\em{\scalebox{1.05}[1]{Solution}}]{%
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \par\noindent\textit{#1\@addpunct{.}}\par\nobreak\smallskip\ignorespaces%
}{%
  \popQED\par\nobreak\smallskip%
}
\makeatother




\makeatletter
\newenvironment{sol}[1][\color{EgyptianBlue}\bf\em{\scalebox{1.05}[1]{Solution}}]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep0\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep\itshape
  #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

If I use the first environment, then I am able to wrap a table but the text in the solution starts in new line. And if I use the second environment, then solution starts in the same line just after the heading "Solution." but I am unable to wrap a table inside the "sol" environment.
I want to use the second environment but want the table to be wrapped and solution to start in the same line just after the word "Solution."
Here are two working examples. In the first MWE I have used the first "sol" environment. With this, I am able to wrap the table but the solution starts in the second line. In the second MWE I have used the second "sol" environment. With this, the solution starts in the first line but table is not wrapping.
First Example:
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amscd, amsfonts, amssymb, graphicx, color,mathtools,wrapfig,tabularray,xcolor,lipsum,booktabs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\definecolor{EgyptianBlue}{RGB}{15,82,186}
\newcommand{\EgyptianBlue}{\color{EgyptianBlue}}
\pagestyle{empty}


\usepackage[text={8in, 11in},
top=0.5in, left=1in, right=1in, bottom=0.5in, includefoot, includehead]{geometry}

\setlength{\intextsep}{5pt} % Space above and below wraptable.
\setlength{\columnsep}{10pt} % Space between wraptable and text.

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{sol}[1][\color{EgyptianBlue}\bf\em{\scalebox{1.05}[1]{Solution}}]{%
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \par\noindent\textit{#1\@addpunct{.}}\par\nobreak\smallskip\ignorespaces%
}{%
  \popQED\par\nobreak\smallskip%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{sol}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{wraptable}{R}{8cm} 
\begin{tblr}{colspec={r|[1pt,white]l|[1pt,white]r|[1pt,white]l},row{even}={gray!30},row{odd}={gray!10},
row{1}={EgyptianBlue!50},columns={40pt}}
\hline[1pt]
$n$&$\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n$&$n$&$\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n$\\
\hline[1pt]
1&2&1000&2.7169\\
5&2.488&10000&2.71814\\
10&2.5937&100000&2.7168268\\
100&2.7048&1000000&2.7182804\\\hline[1pt]
\end{tblr}
\end{wraptable}
\lipsum[2]
\end{sol}
\end{document} 

Second Example:

\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amscd, amsfonts, amssymb, graphicx, color,mathtools,wrapfig,tabularray,xcolor,lipsum,booktabs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\definecolor{EgyptianBlue}{RGB}{15,82,186}
\newcommand{\EgyptianBlue}{\color{EgyptianBlue}}
\pagestyle{empty}


\usepackage[text={8in, 11in},
top=0.5in, left=1in, right=1in, bottom=0.5in, includefoot, includehead]{geometry}

\setlength{\intextsep}{5pt} % Space above and below wraptable.
\setlength{\columnsep}{10pt} % Space between wraptable and text.

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{sol}[1][\color{EgyptianBlue}\bf\em{\scalebox{1.05}[1]{Solution}}]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep0\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep\itshape
  #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{sol}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{wraptable}{R}{8cm} 
\begin{tblr}{colspec={r|[1pt,white]l|[1pt,white]r|[1pt,white]l},row{even}={gray!30},row{odd}={gray!10},
row{1}={EgyptianBlue!50},columns={40pt}}
\hline[1pt]
$n$&$\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n$&$n$&$\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n$\\
\hline[1pt]
1&2&1000&2.7169\\
5&2.488&10000&2.71814\\
10&2.5937&100000&2.7168268\\
100&2.7048&1000000&2.7182804\\\hline[1pt]
\end{tblr}
\end{wraptable}
\lipsum[2]
\end{sol}
\end{document} 

Thanks

Welcome to TeX.SE. Please make your code minimally compilable by indicating (a) which document class is employed and (b) which packages need to be loaded.

The document class is book. Because I am using so many packages, I cannot tell exactly which package is required for this code.

Comment some packages until you find the necessary ones. This is helpful for others to help you. Thanks.

I am trying to find the necessary packages.

I have edited my questions and given two examples with necessary packages.

wrapfig never liked lists. I'm not sure there's much you can do other than using alternatives.

note that \bf has not been defined by default in latex since 1993.  and \em does not take an argument so \em ... not \em{....}

In the first definition, replace \par\nobreak\smallskip by a space, resulting in
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{sol}[1][\color{EgyptianBlue}\bf\em{\scalebox{1.05}[1]{Solution}}]{%
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \par\noindent\textit{#1\@addpunct{.}} \ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\par\nobreak\smallskip%
}
\makeatother

I don't think that the second version can be repaired easily, as the documentation of the wrapfig package says:

You must not specify a wrapfigure in any type of list environment [...]

The second version of the sol environment adds its contents as an \item within a trivlist, and in your example, the contents contains a wraptable environment, which is what the documentation forbids.

Thanks @gernot.
