How to wrap a table created with tabularray
I have created a table using tabularray but am unable to wrap it. Here is MWE. Thanks.
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amscd, amsfonts, amssymb, graphicx, color,mathtools,wrapfig,tabularray,xcolor,lipsum,booktabs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\definecolor{EgyptianBlue}{RGB}{15,82,186}
\newcommand{\EgyptianBlue}{\color{EgyptianBlue}}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[text={8in, 11in},
top=0.5in, left=1in, right=1in, bottom=0.5in, includefoot, includehead]{geometry}

\begin{document}
This is where the table goes with text wrapping around it. You may 
embed tabular environment inside wraptable environment and customize as you like.
\begin{wraptable}{R}{8cm} 
\begin{tblr}{colspec={r|[1pt,white]l|[1pt,white]r|[1pt,white]l},row{even}={gray!30},row{odd}={gray!10},
row{1}={EgyptianBlue!50},columns={40pt}}
\hline[1pt]
$n$&$\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n$&$n$&$\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n$\\
\hline[1pt]
1&2&1000&2.7169\\
5&2.488&10000&2.71814\\
10&2.5937&100000&2.7168268\\
100&2.7048&1000000&2.7182804\\\hline[1pt]
\end{tblr}
\end{wraptable}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX !. Please do consider to update your question in order to include a visual guide of what you want achieve and/or what you have now.

I simply want to wrap the table around the text but with this code table is at the bottom.

Okay, Thanks. I will give you an answer in a minute !

The text does wrap around the table if you add a blank line before \begin{wraptable}. The aspect of the table is not what I'd like to see, but you're the judge about it.

Oh! Thanks. It is working now.

Is the same question you asked? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/733914/unable-to-wrap-a-table-in-solution-environment

I'm not entirely sure if this is exactly what you're aiming to achieve, but you can experiment with this code to get the desired result. You were very close to the solution!
To ensure the table and the wrapped text are visually balanced, it's important to check that there's sufficient space between them. Improper spacing might make the layout look cluttered or uneven. Below, I've provided two example codes that you can use and modify according to your needs:
% Adjust spacing around wraptable.
\setlength{\intextsep}{5pt} % Space above and below wraptable.
\setlength{\columnsep}{10pt} % Space between wraptable and text.

Here's your MWE with the modifications:
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amscd, amsfonts, amssymb, graphicx, color, mathtools, wrapfig, tabularray, xcolor, lipsum, booktabs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\definecolor{EgyptianBlue}{RGB}{15,82,186}
\newcommand{\EgyptianBlue}{\color{EgyptianBlue}}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[text={8in, 11in},
top=0.5in, left=1in, right=1in, bottom=0.5in, includefoot, includehead]{geometry}

% Adjust spacing around wraptable.
\setlength{\intextsep}{5pt} % Space above and below wraptable.
\setlength{\columnsep}{10pt} % Space between wraptable and text.

\begin{document}
This is where the table goes with text wrapping around it. You may embed tabular environment inside wraptable environment and customize as you like.

\begin{wraptable}{R}{8cm} 
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={r|[1pt,white]l|[1pt,white]r|[1pt,white]l},
  row{even}={gray!30},
  row{odd}={gray!10},
  row{1}={EgyptianBlue!50},
  columns={40pt}
}
\hline[1pt]
$n$&$\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n$&$n$&$\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n$\\
\hline[1pt]
1&2&1000&2.7169\\
5&2.488&10000&2.71814\\
10&2.5937&100000&2.7168268\\
100&2.7048&1000000&2.7182804\\
\hline[1pt]
\end{tblr}
\end{wraptable}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}

This produces the following:

Hope it helped.

Thanks Jose Areia. It is working now. I tried to cast you a vote but I need 15 reputations for that.

Is it possible to keep the table at rightmost point without mentioning a length? Thanks.


Culprit of your table is inserting wraptable middle of a paragraph, i.e. before your \begin{wraptable}{R}{8cm} had to be an empty line as is in MWE (Minimal Working Example) below (as was noted in @egreg comment).
Please always provide an MWE, a small but complete document, which reproduce your problem and which in preamble has loaded only to your problem relevant packages as I did in my MWE below.
In my MWE I assume that you may like to have top of table aligned with top of paragraph.

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[text={8in, 11in}, 
            hmargin=0.5in, vmargin=0.5in, 
            includefoot, includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{EgyptianBlue}{RGB}{15,82,186}
    \newcommand{\EgyptianBlue}{\color{EgyptianBlue}} 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,
                 booktabs}
\usepackage{wrapfig}                % or novel `wrapfig2`, if you prefer to enable
                                    % features not used in this particular case
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{wraptable} %
   {\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}}    % remove vertical space above content of
                                    % "wrapfig" at paragraphs, which aren't
                                    % follows section titles
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
This is where the table goes with text wrapping around it. You may 
embed tabular environment inside wraptable environment and customize as you like.

    \begin{wraptable}{R}{8cm} 
\begin{tblr}{vline{2-Y} = {1pt, fg=white},
             colspec   = { r l  r l},
             columns   = {40pt, mode=math},
             row{even} = {gray!30},
             row{odd}  = {gray!10}, 
             row{1}    = {EgyptianBlue!50},
             } 
    \toprule
n   &   \left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n   
                &   n       &   \left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n       \\
    \midrule
1   &   2       &   1000    &   2.7169      \\
5   &   2.488   &   10000   &   2.71814     \\
10  &   2.5937  &   100000  &   2.7168268   \\
100 &   2.7048  &   1000000 &   2.7182804   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{wraptable}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}


I wonder if you really need all packages, which you load in your preamble. BTW, mathtools package load amsmath too, and amssymb use amsfonts, so both not need to be loaded again.


Edit:

you may more liked more compact and balanced table design
for this I remove prescribed column width, employ siunitx tblr library (which load siunitx package) and horizontal center column headers:


\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[text={8in, 11in}, 
            hmargin=0.5in, vmargin=0.5in, 
            includefoot, includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{EgyptianBlue}{RGB}{15,82,186}
    \newcommand{\EgyptianBlue}{\color{EgyptianBlue}} 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,
                 booktabs,
                 siunitx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}                % or novel `wrapfig2`, if you prefer to enable
                                    % features not used in this particular case
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{wraptable} %
   {\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}}    % remove vertical space above content of
                                    % "wrapfig" at paragraphs, which aren't
                                    % follows section titles
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
This is where the table goes with text wrapping around it. You may 
embed tabular environment inside wraptable environment and customize as you like.

    \begin{wraptable}[9]{R}{7cm} 
\begin{tblr}{vline{2-Y} = {1pt, fg=white},
             colspec   = { Q[si={table-format=3.0}] Q[si={table-format=1.4}]
                           Q[si={table-format=7.0}] Q[si={table-format=1.7}] },
             columns   = {c, mode=math},
             row{even} = {gray!30},
             row{odd}  = {gray!10}, 
             row{1}    = {guard, EgyptianBlue!50},
             } 
    \toprule
n   &   \left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n   
                &   n       &   \left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n       \\
    \midrule
1   &   2       &   1000    &   2.7169      \\
5   &   2.488   &   10000   &   2.71814     \\
10  &   2.5937  &   100000  &   2.7168268   \\
100 &   2.7048  &   1000000 &   2.7182804   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{wraptable}
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{document}


As you can see, I in both examples a wee bit change tblr preamble.


This answer should be marked as solved.

As the others have already pointed out, the issue revolves around the lack of
a blank line provided before wrapping your table.
With that being said, I'll propose the wrapstuff package which tries to combine the functionality of multiple wrapping packages. This means that it is also possible to center align the environment you intend to wrap text around quite easily:

You could even add column = false to the wrapstuff environment's optional argument to read the text like a row format instead (but I wouldn't recommend that). A big down-side to this package, however, is its lack of documentation, and so we probably haven't discovered its true potential/versatility yet. Here's the code:
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amscd, amsfonts, amssymb, graphicx, color,mathtools,tabularray,xcolor,lipsum,booktabs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{wrapstuff} % <-- Alternative to wrapfig/wrapfig2
\definecolor{EgyptianBlue}{RGB}{15,82,186}
\newcommand{\EgyptianBlue}{\color{EgyptianBlue}}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[text={8in, 11in},
top=0.5in, left=1in, right=1in, bottom=0.5in, includefoot, includehead]{geometry}

\begin{document}

This is where the table goes with text wrapping around it. You may 
embed tabular environment inside wraptable environment and customize as you like.

\begin{wrapstuff}[c] % <-- Add column=false for row reading order
\begin{tblr}{colspec={r|[1pt,white]l|[1pt,white]r|[1pt,white]l},row{even}={gray!30},row{odd}={gray!10},
row{1}={EgyptianBlue!50},columns={40pt}}
\hline[1pt]
$n$&$\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n$&$n$&$\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n$\\
\hline[1pt]
1&2&1000&2.7169\\
5&2.488&10000&2.71814\\
10&2.5937&100000&2.7168268\\
100&2.7048&1000000&2.7182804\\\hline[1pt]
\end{tblr}
\end{wrapstuff}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}


The wraptable environment will be placed at the next \par command (a blank line generates \par).
You have no \par until the end of \lipsum[2]. In general, it's best to precede wraptable with a blank line (but there are tricks to move it down by a few lines).
Here's a different realization of your table so you can compare them (you may use your style, of course).
The default value of \intextsep is quite large, so I reduce it. With \raggedleft the table is pushed to the right margin.
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[
  text={8in, 11in},
  top=0.5in,
  left=1in,
  right=1in,
  bottom=0.5in,
  includefoot,
  includehead,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{
  amsmath,
  amsthm,
  amssymb,
  graphicx,
  mathtools,
  wrapfig,
  tabularray,
  xcolor,
  lipsum,
  booktabs,
  siunitx,
}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%\definecolor{EgyptianBlue}{RGB}{15,82,186}
%\newcommand{\EgyptianBlue}{\color{EgyptianBlue}}

%\pagestyle{empty}

\setlength{\intextsep}{1ex}

\begin{document}

This is where the table goes with text wrapping around it. 
You may embed tabular environment inside wraptable environment 
and customize as you like.

\begin{wraptable}{R}{8cm}
\raggedleft
\sisetup{group-digits=integer}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=1.4]
  @{\hspace{4em}}
  S[table-format=7.0]
  S[table-format=1.7]
  @{}
}
\toprule
{$n$} & {$\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{\!n}$} &
{$n$} & {$\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{\!n}$} \\
\midrule
1 & 2 & 1000 & 2.7169 \\
5 & 2.488 & 10000 & 2.71814 \\
10 & 2.5937 & 100000 & 2.7168268 \\
100 & 2.7048 & 1000000 & 2.7182804 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{wraptable}

\lipsum*[2]

\end{document}


